# connecting to WSDL URL throws MalformedURLException: no protocol

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, cxf

We have a web service that is running on a web server. A web app (currently running on localhost) tries to access it. I can call the location in my browser and it will show me the WSDL so the web service is working. Also if I run the web app against the same service running on my localhost, it will work.

But if I try to connect to the remote web service it will give me a

`java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: <URL here>`

which will be wrapped by the wsdl2java generated Service class into

```
Can not initialize the default wsdl from <web service location here>
```

Yes, the URL is really working. It is there and running...

What could cause this? Do I need to set permissions or open a port on the remote web service server? (We're using CXF for the web service)

Thanks!

Comment: May be the remote URL is really wrong... Can you post the two URLs?

Comment: No, the URL is correct. I took the URL from the exception message and pasted it 1:1 into my browser. It was right there... Unfotunately I can't to post the WS location, company policy..

Comment: No protocol comes when the provided URL doesn't have an associated protocol. Like if http://, file://. So please check if its there. Browsers can take html protocol automatically even if you don't specify it.

Comment: Ah, that might be it! I access the remote server via its `IP.Add.ress.here/wsdlPath` and my localhost via `http://localhost/wsdlPath`. Handling some other trouble right now and will check it right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Thihara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/272451/thihara) I found the problem:
When accessing my local wsdl service I used

```
"http://localhost/pathToWsdl"
```

But when trying to access the remote wsdl I used

```
"ip.add.res.s/pathToWsdl"
```

So obviously there was no protocol in the latter and thus the exception.